# How to implement fulfillment for alpha/beta releases actions google

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I've been developing on Actions on Google using Dialogflow. The webhooks worked like charm when using the simulator for testing.

I published an Alpha released but it isn't working at all. The Alpha testers can't get it connect and when I tested that Alpha version on the simulator, it tells " isn't responding right now. Try again soon."

In the documentation "Releasing Your Actions to Alpha and Beta Environments", a paragraph reads:
"Implement fulfillment for alpha/beta releases
The release channel information is not included in the HTTP request from the Assistant to your fulfillment. To handle release channels in your fulfillment, you should provide different fulfillment URLs (for example, one fulfillment URL for the beta and another URL for the production version of your Action)"

I searched everywhere and I could not find any pointers on how to implement a new fulfillment for the Alpha (and eventually the published release).
I have one url that I use in the fulfillment on Dialogflow, so how can I do otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same webhook will work for all the versions, (at least it is working for aplha in my case), check for one of the following cases...

1. Make sure you have added Alpha testers' mail addresses to **alpha testers list**, otherwise they will not be able to access the alpha release.
2. Make sure you have deployed the latest updated version of agent on *actions on google* page. If not do so,
   [image]
   If you are getting a "modified action" message like this, that means you have a change that is not yet deployed.
3. **Deployment of agent is not instant and takes quite a bit of time** to get accessible on Google actions platforms. Check the current release status of your latest deployment, it should show **"deployed"**, if it's showing **"deploying"** you have to wait for some time to get it deployed.
4. If all of the above is Ok, test the alpha release and check out your web-hook log (even check if web-hook is at least receiving the requests or not) , that will be the only place where you will find any possible error.

Comment: 1. The Alpha testers are to the list, they can access the opt-in url and can see the app when they search it in "Explore"
2. I do have some modified actions but these are very recent Drafts after I've already submitted an Alpha release. The status for that release shows as:
Release: Version 1 Deployed
3. It's been 8 hours and it shows as Deployed.
4. The webhook doesn't seem to be triggered at all, I get nothing anymore on my server-side.

The current Draft works fine on the simulator, once I change the version to Alpha, it tells "<app_name> isn't responding right now. Try again soon.

Comment: As web-hook server is not receiving the requests at all, you might have changed the fulfillment url in dialogflow in recent version which is not yet deployed. So the deployed release may be still using the old url

Comment: I believe the same fulfillment urls are the same. Also, my app start with a default welcome intent that does not require any webhooks, even that is not happening. 
Anyway, I am starting a new Alpha version now. Clicked Test that version and seems fine, still deploying, hoping it worked when deployed.

Also, in draft simulator, my Development Sandbox is Enabled. Do I need to setup anything on Google Cloud to start billing me. I have no done anything beyond dialogflow and Actions, never set up an account or billing anywhere else.

Comment: IMO, if you are not using Google Cloud Functions or (maybe) Firebase for fulfillment then there is no need to setup billing for just dialogflow and actions. I used Cloud functions for fulfillment and thus I am not sure about Firebase part.